# Rremove extra spaces in Tab host implementation in Android

Tags: android

I have a question that I am implementing a tab bar in my android app but Tab host displays some extra margins from left, right, top and bottom which is looking so ugly, So how can we remove these extra spaces from Tab Host. You can understand easily by attached picture with red circled extra spaces.

Please suggest me the right answer regarding the same.

**Xml Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip" android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip" xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
         <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
            />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: I am not understanding your red lines please upload some other oitcure 
or make it clear

Comment: It would be better if you post your xml layout code here.

Comment: tab host usually does not create this kind of problems.. i think you have a problem with the layouts that actually hold tabHost, so try to modify your main layout, where you host your tabHost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `android:padding` set container layout of your `TabHost` or you have `android:layout_margin` set in the layout you add to the container.

Post both XML files if you want more specific help.

**Edit**

Based on your XML file you have `android:padding="5dp"` set in both your `FrameLayout` and your `LinearLayout`. Remove those, and you the excesive padding will dissappear.

Comment: Hello Kasper there is no any extra padding and margins in xml, I have attached the same please see that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Your `android:padding="0px"` or you can remove your padding or try `android:layoutMargin` or `android:padding`
or you try to gime some code